# Proving existence of maximal sum-free set containing $\{1,7,9\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was asked to prove:

> Prove there exists a maximal sum-free set that contains the set $\{1,7,9\}$

We say a set of natural numbers is sum-free if no element in it is the sum of a finite number of other elements in the set, with no repetition of the elements in the summation.

and the hint was to use Zorn's lemma.

So I defined a set $A=\{B\subseteq\mathbb{N}:\{1,7,9\}\subseteq B\text{ and } B \text{ is sum-free}\}$
And the order is inclusion, $\subseteq$.

Now I'd like to show that $A$ has a maximal element.
This can be obtained from Zorn's lemma if I can show that every chain in $A$ has an upper bound. This is where I'm stuck.

Any idea on how to prove that every chain in $A$ has an upper bound?

(I've got no intuition as to why such a maximal set should exist in the first place...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is similar to the proof that the increasing union of functions is a function; or the increasing union of linearly independent sets is a linearly independent set.

If $C$ is a chain, and $B=\bigcup C$, then assume towards contradiction that $B$ is not sum-free, and derive that there was an element in $C$ which was already not sum-free.

---

It should be noted that in the case of $\Bbb N$, which can be enumerated, we can just proceed by induction and go over all the elements, then add at each step the elements which did not violate the sum-freeness of what previously was accumulated.

So there is no real need for Zorn's lemma here.

Comment: Thanks. Using $B=\cup C$ was actually what I initially tried, but I confused the definitions.